# Django: Pre-populate form with request data

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to pre-populate a Django form based on a users POST request data. Am using FormView, so i overide get_initial but request.POST is always empty. I guess am missing something

below is snippet from my view

```
def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(Yo_EnView, self).get_initial()
        if self.request.POST:
            initial.update({'src': self.request.src})
        return initial
```

Comment: Can you add the whole view code? Or at least the class signature, `get()` and `post()` methods. That would help!

Comment: Is `.src` a parameter from the `request.POST`? If so, it should be accessed through either `request.POST['src']` or `request.POST.get('src')`.